# “list label” operator not working for a set of alternatives

Tags: antlr, antlr4

It seems the following rule will not work in antlr4

```
testSetLabel
    : (flags+=( 'A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D' ))* ;
```

It will give this error:

```
TestSetLabelParser.java:69: error: incompatible types
                ((TestSetLabelContext)_localctx).flags = _input.LT(1);
                                                                  ^
  required: List<Token>
  found:    Token
```

If I change the rule to this:

```
testSetLabel2
: ( flags+= 'A' | flags+='B' | flags+='C' | flags+='D' )* ;
```

I get warning: 'Factor label out of set'

Is this a bug or expected behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a bug. The `=` operator works, as in the following case.

```
flags=('A' | 'B' | 'C' | 'D')
```

The message you are seeing is only a performance suggestion, so I would use the working method for now and factor the label out of the set when ANTLR 4.1 comes out at the end of June.

[Here is the issue report](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/issues/270)